# Reading data from magnetic stripe reader

Tags: c#

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have a magnetic stripe reader, that uses KB wedge, but since my laptop doesnt have a kb wedge i am using it with usb extension.

I want to make a simple magnetic stripe reading program, that just reads and displays data read from the card.

I don't know how to get started with this, and i have a couple of questions:

1) cant find a driver for this particular reader on the net. do i even need one?
2) what C# class must be used for reading input( and if possible, how to use it  )?

Any kind of help is more than welcome!

Comment: I guess you need to know how data is stored in this stripe. If its a custom format, then driver is necessary unless you know how to do reverse engineering on it.

Comment: so i cant just use some C# class to read data directly from it? and then figuring out what it means.

Comment: It's not that you can't use C# to read the data, the problem is, you won't know what the data is. Imagine looking at a series of 1's and 0's on your hard disk and trying to decipher meaning from it without understanding the file system being used on it. It's the same idea.

Comment: So im in trouble. I cant find the driver anywhere on the net. i cant even find manufacturers page. magnetic stripe reader is POSLINK. Anyone heard of it? model is PS-100...something. can't see

Comment: As per wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card take alook at financial card section there its talking about protocols being used and the data storage format.